# Combine image outlines with another image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Let's say I have this [image](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=python%20%20outlines%20image&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=B1U4OnbTAxhLpM%253A%252Cu7J5t2qmpmoPyM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kQ0HkxYgQXDsbTsHo1oqOA6yZUoow&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTwrXHrLHeAhUMQRoKHfKuArkQ9QEwAHoECAYQBA#imgrc=B1U4OnbTAxhLpM:) as numpy array. all of the white pixels are 1's and the blacks are zeros. I also have this [image](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Bv3ZW-cYipyTBcWwmcgO&q=forest&oq=forest&gs_l=img.3..0l10.106609.108783.0.109060.8.8.0.0.0.0.129.712.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.6.710.0..35i39k1j0i67k1.0.exjRNoxqyqk#imgrc=zETgslHFZXAZQM:) as numpy array. I want to take the snqke from the first image without the white background and paste it on the forest image, using python. anyone here know how to do this ?

Comment: The image you link to is a vector image, i.e. SVG format and Pillow/PIL is a raster processor, not a vector processor, so you cannot open an SVG file with Pillow AFAIK. Or do you mean you have a JPEG file? Or a PNG file?

Comment: thanks for the reply! edited the question. both images as nupy arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it would be more instructive, and fun, to make the snake red - you can obviously dink around as much as you like now you have something that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

snake  = Image.open('snake.jpg').convert('L')
forest = Image.open('forest.jpg').convert('RGB')

# Make sensible sizes
snakedims = (100,150)
snake  = snake.resize(snakedims)
forest = forest.resize((600,800))

# Make into numpy arrays
snakenp  = np.array(snake)
forestnp = np.array(forest)

# Top-left corner of where we want snake to appear
topleft = 300,500

# Create an ROI - Region of Interest - same size as snake
roi = forestnp[topleft[1]:topleft[1]+snakedims[1], topleft[0]:topleft[0]+snakedims[0], :]

# Everywhere in the ROI where the snake is less than 128, put red (255,0,0)
roi[snakenp<128] = 255,0,0

# Save result to disk
Image.fromarray(forestnp).save('result.png')
```

[image]